# How to insert HTML table as TCPDF Object in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, html-table, syntax, tcpdf

I am trying to get a table in PDF downloadable, but the problem is I am using selection statements with loops for retrieving data. The table is working fine without loops.

I have gone through these examples https://tcpdf.org/examples/ and getting problem when retrieve data by loops.

This is the table I want to pass from template to $html variable(PDF object):

```
<h2 align ="center" bgcolor ="#75777a">Order Pick List</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
<th>Col 3</th>
<th>Col 4</th>
</tr>
<?php $Orders= $block->getOrders();
foreach ($Orders as $order) {
    $Colone = $order->getID();
    $Coltwo = $order->getName();
    $items = $order->getitems();?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $Colone; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Coltwo; ?></td>

        <?php foreach ($items as $item ) {
            $itemName = $item->getitemName();?>

            <td>
                <?php echo $itemName; ?>
            </td>

        <?php } ?>
    </tr>

<?php}
?>
```

Has anyone done anything similar they wish to share to get me started?

Comment: Do we get any context?  What does sample input data look like?  What is your expected result?  You are "**getting problem**"? What is the problem exactly?  (Unclear / Why isn't my code working)

Comment: what are you not getting ? can u explain more.

Comment: Explain more.  Yes, please do that very thing. [mcve]

Comment: It is simple PDF Object, that we pass as html while using TCPDF Library. I am getting problem in php code particularly with loops when retrieving data.

Comment: What isn't working? I can't vote this question Unclear more than once, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve your problem in this way

```
public function getHtml()
{
$html = '';
$tempItem1 = '';
$tempitemQuantity = '';
$html = '<h1 bgcolor ="#75777a" align = "center">Order Pick List</h1>';
$html.= '<table border= "1">';
$html.= '<tr>
<th><b>Col 1</b></th>
<th><b>Col 2</b></th>
<th><b>Col 3</b></th>
<th><b>Col 4</b></th>
</tr>';
$_data = $this->order->getOrders();
foreach ($_data as $value){
$tempItem1 = '';
$tempitemQuantity = '';
$OrderId = $value->getEntityId();;
$tempName1= $value->getCustomerName();
$OrderItems = $value->getAllItems();
foreach ($OrderItems as $item) {
$tempitemQuantity.= $item->getQtyOrdered().'<br />';
$tempItem1.= $item->getName().'<br />';
}
$html.='<tr>
<td>'.$OrderId.'</td>
<td>'.$tempName1.'</td>
<td>'.$tempItem1.'</td>
<td>'.$tempitemQuantity.'</td>
</tr>';
}
$html.='</table>';
return $html;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only / _Try this_ answers. What does this answer solve?  Why is it a good idea?  Answers should endeavor to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers. Please indent your snippet.  Please improve this post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , just show the basic frame of the code to be worked that fits for specific purpose

Comment: So you don't actually know that this code will work for the question asked?  Sounds like the question is Unclear to you.  Perhaps wait to answer until you better understand the question.

Comment: The logic is fine and improved and hopefully it will work 90%

Comment: Thanks, sheraz and mickmackusa for attention. This logic works for me.